# cast RSAPrivateKey to PrivateKey and vice versa

Tags: java, bouncycastle, asn.1, der

I've created an `org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPrivateKey` using its static  `getInstance(byte[])` from a PKCS#1 formated DER bytes,
now I want to cast(or change) this to PrivateKey, how to do that??

Answer (score 0):

You can directly create the PrivateKey from an ASN.1 encoded bytes array.

```
public static PrivateKey makeKey(byte[] keyBytes) {
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    KeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
    return privateKey;
}
```

Comment: the bytes are not PKCS8 encoded so this probably will throw invalidkeyException

Comment: `RSAPrivateKey` doesn't have `getInstance(byte[])` method. http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/asn1/pkcs/RSAPrivateKey.html#getInstance%28org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1TaggedObject,%20boolean%29